# When Using Google identity services for Authorization code Flow - client.requestCode() Method is Undefined

Tags: javascript, authorization, google-identity

When using the google authorisation code flow as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model#popup-mode

```
client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES,
          ux_mode: 'popup',
          callback: (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', URI , true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            // Set custom header for CRSF
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XmlHttpRequest');
            xhr.onload = function() {
              console.log('Auth code response: ' + xhr.responseText);
            };
            xhr.send('code=' + response.code);
          },
        });
```

but when trying to call `client.requestCode()` to request authorisation code. Console just prints error showing

TypeError: client.requestCode() is not a function

I already checked for spelling issues, check if google identity services is loaded but still cannot resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

My Mistake, I have been using InitTokenClient method to initialise client, where I have to use initCodeClient to access authorization code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).